# Windows Network Bridge Connections Greyed Out

Tags: windows-xp, networking, network-adapter, group-policy, bridge

I can bridge the connection under administrator account. I have [disabled the prohibit installation and configuration of Network Bridge on your DNS domain network Group Policy setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758455%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). The option to bridge has appeared in the ordinary user account but it is gray and cannot be used. Can I enable this option for our students?